# Why rank($rank) doesn't allow multiple sortBy fields?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-8, ranking

I am getting an issue when trying to rank documents based on score and attempts

```
"$rank must be specified with a top level sortBy expression with exactly one element"
```

The query is :

```
$resultListing = UserScore::raw(function ($collection){
    return $collection->aggregate([
        ['$setWindowFields' => [
            'sortBy' => [ 'score'=>-1, 'attempts'=>1],
            'output' => [ 'scoreRank' => ['$rank'=>(object) [] ] ],
        ]]
    ]);
});
```

The syntax given was:

```
{
  $setWindowFields: {
  partitionBy: <expression>,
  sortBy: {
     <sort field 1>: <sort order>,
     <sort field 2>: <sort order>,
     ...,
     <sort field n>: <sort order>
  },
```

Is it possible to rank docs based on multiple fields?

Comment: its the `$rank` as far as i know allows 1 sort field, but i cant find the documentation to be sure, it happened to me in past, in docs the only thing i found is this `Range
 and 
time range
 windows can only contain one 
sortBy
 field and the sort must be ascending.`

Comment: @tyro the only limitation is to sort with [32 keys](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#limits).